# Class has two properties of the same name "actionsList"

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

still have some problems with jaxb !

In fact yesterday i changed my code in the way to find the issue to jaxb and interfaces and since that i have this problem with the two properties with the same name...

I looked for but i have a special case of @XmlElements{...}.

If i write like this it works

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Event {

String name;
@XmlElements(value = {
        @XmlElement(type=FTPSend.class),
        @XmlElement(type=SFTPSend.class),
        @XmlElement(type=MailSend.class),
        @XmlElement(type=ServerToServerSend.class)
    })
ArrayList<IAction> actionsList = new ArrayList<IAction>();

public Event(){

}

public Event(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public ArrayList<IAction> getActionsList() {
    return actionsList;
}

public void setActionsList(ArrayList<IAction> actionsList) {
    this.actionsList = actionsList;
}
```

}

But if i add the @XmlElement, i have two errors, one with jaxb can't handle interfaces and the other one with same name

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Event {

String name;
@XmlElements(value = {
        @XmlElement(type=FTPSend.class),
        @XmlElement(type=SFTPSend.class),
        @XmlElement(type=MailSend.class),
        @XmlElement(type=ServerToServerSend.class)
    })
ArrayList<IAction> actionsList = new ArrayList<IAction>();

public Event(){

}

public Event(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

**@XmlElement**
public ArrayList<IAction> getActionsList() {
    return actionsList;
}

public void setActionsList(ArrayList<IAction> actionsList) {
    this.actionsList = actionsList;
}
```

}

And unfortunately i need to add the @XmlElement to build my xml file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you annotate a field and it's corresponding property you will get an exception, you need to do just one or the other.

For unmarshalling your JAXB implementation is going to require some indication as to the correct class to unmarshal.  Below I have assigned each class a unique element name.  This mapping corresponds to a choice structure in an XML Schema.

```
@XmlElements(value = {
    @XmlElement(type=FTPSend.class, name="FTPSend"),
    @XmlElement(type=SFTPSend.class, name="SFTPSend"),
    @XmlElement(type=MailSend.class, name="MailSend"),
    @XmlElement(type=ServerToServerSend.class, name="ServerToServerSend")
})
ArrayList<IAction> actionsList = new ArrayList<IAction>();
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html